# how to translate regula expression from php to java

Tags: java, php, regex

php code

```
$contentHtml = ".....";
preg_match('/;ytplayer\.config\s*=\s*({.*?});/', $contentHtml, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

how to using this expression on java/android ?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/;ytplayer\.config\s*=\s*({.*?});/");
// error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

thank you.

Comment: sorry for basic question, i'm java beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java regex would be,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";ytplayer\\.config\\s*=\\s*(\\{.*?});");
```

You don't need to use php regex delimiters in Java. That is starting `/` and ending `/` symbol. And you have to escape `\` one more time in java.

**Example:**

```
String s = ";ytplayer.config = {foo bar};";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(";ytplayer\\.config\\s*=\\s*(\\{.*?});");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
{foo bar}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you don't use delimiters for your regular expression and you need double backslashes.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";ytplayer\\.config\\s*=\\s*(\\{.*?\\});");
```